# javascript - click() doesn`t work in chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, click

I have tried this, (note that I am using jQuery):

```
function HandleFileButtonClick()
{
    1. //$('#filesel').click();
    2. //document.replyform.image.click();
}
```

HTML:

```
<input type="file" id="filesel" name="image" style="display: none;"  /> 
<a href="#"><img src="<?=TF?>/img/att.png" style="height:20px;" onclick="HandleFileButtonClick();" /></a>
```

neither are working in Google Chrome Browser... any ideas, or a replacement for jQuery click()

Comment: Also see [Chrome and Firefox file upload browse bug](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5812174/chrome-and-firefox-file-upload-browse-bug).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sounds like you are hitting a security wall designed to only allow the file upload box to be triggered by the user.

You could try absolutely positioning the browser's `browse` button over your link, and then setting its `opacity` to `0`.

Comment: Nope /. not a security wall, the click event works when it's not hidden. It's (i believe) an optimization feature, i.e. remove all listeners on display:none events, since they shouldn't be clicked from there.

Answer (score 5):

I am here to help other with a similar problem. I try use .trigger('click') to start a click event into a FILE field that was if style='display:none' and discovered that Chrome diferent from Mozila Firefox and IE don´t let it work with this style.
The solution is don´t use display:none and use instead of it style='width:0px;height:0px'. The result is the same, the FILE field be hidden and you can use another button to start its works even in Chrome this time.

Best Regards peeps.

Comment: Great solution, should get more attention !

Comment: Also, I just found that by using visibility:hidden; Chrome DOES let it work (and Firefox, and Opera, and Safari, but didn't try with Explorer).

Answer (score 2):

Dont't use removeClass or addClass, or width:1px for the real file inputs. Just use simple CSS: `visiblity: hidden; position: absolute;`

This will fix all your problems in this case!

Answer (score 1):

What are you trying to accomplish?

Maybe this is what you want:

```
function HandleFileButtonClick()
{
    ...
}

$('#filesel').click(HandleFileButtonClick);
```

<strike>**Note:**</strike>

> <strike>If you are trying to trigger mouse click event by calling click function of JQuery, you are totally out of track. This cannot be achieved.</strike>

Comment: so why does it work in any other browser except chrome ?.. i`m not an expert of javascript/jquery but i think you are out of track... btw, function is called with onclick="" no need for $('#filesel').click(HandleFileButtonClick);

Comment: @Andrei, Really, Does it really trigger click event?, If so I would like to learn it. Can you point me to some link/doc where I can learn about it.

Comment: you can see here: http://api.jquery.com/click/ 

Description: Bind an event handler to the "click" JavaScript event, or trigger that event on an element.

Answer (score 1):

instead of using CSS fixes to hide the file field offscreen/out of sight without the use of `display:none`, I use the following strategy:

The CSS:

```
.hidden {display:none}
```

The HTML

```
<input type="file" name="file-upload" id="file-upload" class="hidden" /><button>Upload</button>
```

in prototype:

```
$('file-upload').removeClassName('hidden').click();$('file-upload').addClassName('hidden');
```

in jQuery:

```
$('#file-upload').removeClass('hidden').click().addClass('hidden');
```

This beats wrestling with different browser styles in my opinion. Works for me!