# How FileReader.readAsText in HTML5 File API works?

Tags: javascript, html, drag-and-drop, textarea, fileapi

I wrote the following code to check whether the uploaded file exists or not using HTML5 file API.

```html
<input type="file" id="myfile">
<button type="button" onclick="addDoc()">Add Document</button>
<p id="DisplayText"></p>
```

The following JavaScript code has been mapped to it is as follows:

```
function addDoc() {
  var file=document.getElementById("myFile").files[0]; //for input type=file
  var reader=new FileReader();
  reader.onload = function(e) {}
  reader.readAsText(file);
  var error = reader.error;
  var texte=reader.result;
  document.getElementById("DisplayText").innerText=reader.result; /*<p id="DisplayText>*/
}
```

After browsing a file from local system I tried to delete the "browsed" document form the folder before clicking on `addDoc()`. After clicking the button I could still see `Filereader.result` is not null and could display all the content.

Can someone explain on how the *Filereader* works? Is it that the *FileReader* gets bound as soon as the file is browsed?

Also can we check whether the system *Readonly* Attribute with *FileReader* similar to Java `File.canread()`?

Could someone suggest on this? I have IE11 to test the code.

Answer (score 18):

`FileReader` `load` event sets the `.result` value asynchronously. To access the `.result` use `load` or `loadend` event.

When a file has been selected at `<input type="file">` `Choose File` or `Browse...` UI, deleting file at local filesystem should not effect the `File` object at `FileList` returned by `.files` call. See [2.9.2. Transferable objects](http://w3c.github.io/html/infrastructure.html#section-transferable-objects), [6.7.3 The DataTransfer interface](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/interaction.html#the-datatransfer-interface).

> [4. The Blob Interface and Binary Data](https://w3c.github.io/FileAPI/#blob)
>
> Each [`Blob`](https://w3c.github.io/FileAPI/#dfn-Blob) must have an internal ***snapshot state***, which
>   must be initially set to the state of the underlying storage, if any
>   such underlying storage exists, and must be preserved through
>   [`structured clone`](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/infrastructure.html#structured-clone). Further normative definition of [`snapshot state`](https://w3c.github.io/FileAPI/#snapshot-state) can be found for [`File`](https://w3c.github.io/FileAPI/#dfn-file)s.

> [2.9.8 Monkey patch for Blob and FileList objects](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/infrastructure.html#monkey-patch-for-blob-and-filelist-objects)
>
> This monkey patch will be removed in due course. See [w3c/FileAPI
>   issue 32](https://github.com/w3c/FileAPI/issues/32).
>
> `Blob` objects are [`cloneable objects`](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/infrastructure.html#cloneable-objects).
>
> 1. Each `Blob` object's [[[`Clone`](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/infrastructure.html#clone)]] internal method, given targetRealm and ignoring memory, must run these steps:
> 2. If this is [`closed`](https://w3c.github.io/FileAPI/#closed), then throw a [`"DataCloneError"`](https://heycam.github.io/webidl/#datacloneerror) [`DOMException`](https://heycam.github.io/webidl/#dfn-DOMException).
>
> Return a new instance of **this** in *targetRealm*, corresponding to
>   the same underlying data.
>
> [`FileList`](https://w3c.github.io/FileAPI/#filelist-section) objects are [cloneable objects](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/infrastructure.html#cloneable-objects).
>
> Each `FileList` object's `[[Clone]]` internal method, given
>   *targetRealm* and *memory*, must run these steps:
>
> 1. Let *output* be a new `FileList` object in *targetRealm*.
> 2. For each *file* in **this**, add ? `[StructuredClone][15](_file, targetRealm, memory_)` to the end of the list of [`File`](https://w3c.github.io/FileAPI/#file) objects
>      of *output*.
>
> Return *output*.

---

## Selecting read-only files or folders at webkit and firefox browsers

At chrome, chromium if read-only permission is set for file at local filesystem and user selects file at `<input type="file">` element, where `FileReader` is used to read file, an error is thrown at `FileReader`, generated from `FileReader` `progress` event.

If a `Blob URL` is set to the same file object, the `blob:` URL will not return the the read-only file at request to the `Blob URL`.

### Selection of folder where folder permission is set to read-only

#### Chrome, chromium

At chrome, chromium where `webkitdirectory` attribute is set and folder is selected with read-only permission `FileList` `.length` of `event.target.files` returned `0`; `event.target.files.webkitGetAsEntry()` is not called, `"No file chosen"` is rendered at `<input type="file">` `shadowDOM`. When a folder is dropped at `<input type="file">` or element where `droppable` attribute set, the directory `.name` and `.path` of the read-only folder is displayed at `drop` `event.dataTransfer`.

When user drops file or folder at `<textarea>` element, where no `drop` event is attached `beforeunload` event is called and a prompr is displayed at UI

> ```
> Do you want to leave this site?
> Changes you made may not be saved.
> <Stay><Leave> // <buttons>
> ```

#### Firefox

At firefox version 47.0b9 with `allowdirs` attribute is set at `<input type="file">` element, where user clicks `"Choose folder.."` `<input>`, the folder `.name` and `.path` of the parent folder are accessible at `.then()` chained to `event.target.getFilesAndDirectories()`. The files or folders contained within the selected folder are not returned when recursively iterating `Directory` entries; an an empty string is returned.

If user clicks `"Choose file..."` `<input>` and a folder is selected without read-only permission set, when the folder at file manager is clicked, the files in the folder are listed.

Where a folder is selected where read-only permission is set an `alert()` notification is rendered at UI displaying

> ```
>   Could not read the contents of <directory name>
>   Permission denied
> ```

### ## Bug, security issue

*nix OS

When user drops folder at `<textarea>` element, where no `drop` event is attached, the full path to the folder at user filesystem `file:` protocol is exposed. The paths to the files contained within the folder are not also set as `.value`; e.g.,

```
"file:///home/user/Documents/Document/"
```

When a file is dropped at `<textarea>` element, where not `drop` event is attached, the full path to the file at user filesystem is set as `.value` of `<textarea>`; that is,

```
"file:///home/user/Documents/Document/MyFileFullPathDisplayedAtTextAreaValue.txt"
```

If multiple files are selected and dropped at `<textarea>` element, all of the full file paths are set as `.value` of `<textarea>`, delineated by new line character `\n`

```
"file:///home/user/Documents/Document/MyFileFullPathDisplayedAtTextAreaValue1.txt"
"file:///home/user/Documents/Document/MyFileFullPathDisplayedAtTextAreaValue2.txt"
..
```

Where an `XMLHttpRequest()` is made for the file path and error is logged at `console`

```
NS_ERROR_DOM_BAD_URI: Access to restricted URI denied
```

When set as `.src` of an `<img>` element with `.crossOrigin` set to `"anonymous"` the `img` `error` event handler is called

At call to `window.open()` with full path set at first parameter

```
Error: Access to '"file:///home/user/Documents/Document/MyFileFullPathDisplayedAtTextAreaValue.png"' from script denied
```

### Specification

[4.10.5.1.18. File Upload state (`type=file`)](https://w3c.github.io/html/sec-forms.html#file-upload-state-typefile)

> [EXAMPLE 16](https://w3c.github.io/html/sec-forms.html#example-8eea6b94)
>
> For historical reasons, the [`value`](https://w3c.github.io/html/sec-forms.html#dom-htmlinputelement-value) IDL attribute prefixes the
>   file name with the string "`C:\fakepath\`". Some legacy user agents
>   actually included the full path (which was a security vulnerability).
>   As a result of this, obtaining the file name from the `value` IDL
>   attribute in a backwards-compatible way is non-trivial.

[4.10.5.4. Common `<input>` element APIs](https://w3c.github.io/html/sec-forms.html#common-input-element-apis)

> ***filename***
>
> On getting, it must return the string "C:\fakepath\" followed by the name of the first file in the list of [`selected
>   files`](https://w3c.github.io/html/sec-forms.html#selected-files), if any, or the empty string if the list is empty. On
>   setting, if the new value is the empty string, it must empty the list
>   of `selected files`; otherwise, it must throw an "`InvalidStateError`"
>   `DOMException`.
>
> > **NOTE:** This "fakepath" requirement is a sad accident of history. See the example in the [File Upload](https://w3c.github.io/html/sec-forms.html#element-statedef-input-file-upload) state section for more
> >     information.
> >
> > **NOTE:** Since `path components` are not permitted in file names in the list of `selected files`, the "`\fakepath\`" cannot be mistaken
> >     for a path component.

[4.10.5.1.18. File Upload state (`type=file`)](https://w3c.github.io/html/sec-forms.html#file-upload-state-typefile)

### Path components

> When an `<input>` element’s `type` attribute is in the `File Upload`
>   state, the rules in this section apply.
>
> The `<input>` element [`represents`](https://w3c.github.io/html/dom.html#represent) a list of `selected files`,
>   each file consisting of a file name, a file type, and a file body (the
>   contents of the file).
>
> File names must not contain [`path components`](https://w3c.github.io/html/sec-forms.html#path-components), even in the case that a
>   user has selected an entire directory hierarchy or multiple files with
>   the same name from different directories. **Path components**, for the
>   purposes of the `File Upload` state, are those parts of file names
>   that are separated by U+005C REVERSE SOLIDUS character () characters.

Bug report https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1311823

---

#### Dropping file at <textarea> at data URI

Following comment by [Neal Deakin](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1311823#c13) at bug report

> I think the steps referred to are:
>
> 1. Open data:text/html,
> 2. Drag a file from the desktop to the textarea
>
> I can reproduce this on Linux, but not on Windows or Mac.
>
> The hunch above is correct; Linux is including the data as a url and
>   plaintext as well.

dropped files at `data:` prototcol `data URI` at firefox, and chrome, chromium

```
data:text/html,<textarea></textarea>
```

#### Firefox

The full path name of file or folder set as `.value` of `<textarea>`.

#### Chrome, chromium

Dropping file at `data URI` having only `textarea` element at chrome, chromium replaces the `data URI` with dropped file path at address bar, and loads the dropped file at the same tab, replacing the `data URI` with the content of the dropped file.

plnkr http://plnkr.co/edit/ZfAGEAiyLLq8rGXD2ShE?p=preview

---

`html`, `javascript` to reproduce issue described above

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <style>
    body {
      height: 400px;
    }

    textarea {
      width: 95%;
      height: inherit;
    }
  </style>

  <script>
    window.onload = function() {
      var button = document.querySelector("#myfile + button");
      var input = document.getElementById("myfile");
      var display = document.getElementById("DisplayText");
      var text = null;

      function readFullPathToFileOnUserFileSystem(e) {
        var path = e.target.value;
        console.log(path);
        var w = window.open(path, "_blank");
        var img = new Image;
        img.crossOrigin = "anonymous";
        img.onload = function() {
          document.body.appendChild(this);
        }
        img.onerror = function(err) {
          console.log("img error", err.message)
        }
        img.src = path;
        var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
        request.open("GET", path.trim(), true);
        request.onload = function() {
          console.log(this.responseText)
        }
        request.error = function(err) {
          console.log(err.message)
        }
        request.send();

      }

      display.addEventListener("input", readFullPathToFileOnUserFileSystem);
      input.addEventListener("change", addDoc);
      input.addEventListener("progress", function(event) {
        console.log("progress", event)
      });
      button.addEventListener("click", handleText)

      function addDoc(event) {
        var mozResult = [];

        function mozReadDirectories(entries, path) {
          console.log("dir", entries, path);
          return [].reduce.call(entries, function(promise, entry) {
              return promise.then(function() {
                console.log("entry", entry);
                return Promise.resolve(entry.getFilesAndDirectories() || entry)
                  .then(function(dir) {
                    console.log("dir getFilesAndDirectories", dir)
                    return dir
                  })
              })
            }, Promise.resolve())
            .catch(function(err) {
              console.log(err, err.message)
            })
            .then(function(items) {
              console.log("items", items);
              var dir = items.filter(function(folder) {
                return folder instanceof Directory
              });
              var files = items.filter(function(file) {
                return file instanceof File
              });
              if (files.length) {
                console.log("files:", files, path);
                mozResult = mozResult.concat.apply(mozResult, files);

              }
              if (dir.length) {
                console.log(dir, dir[0] instanceof Directory, dir[0]);
                return mozReadDirectories(dir, dir[0].path || path);

              } else {
                if (!dir.length) {

                  return Promise.resolve(mozResult).then(function(complete) {
                    return complete
                  })

                }
              }

            })
            .catch(function(err) {
              console.log(err)
            })

        };

        console.log("files", event.target.files);
        if ("getFilesAndDirectories" in event.target) {
          return (event.type === "drop" ? event.dataTransfer : event.target)
          .getFilesAndDirectories()
            .then(function(dir) {
              if (dir[0] instanceof Directory) {
                console.log(dir)
                return mozReadDirectories(dir, dir[0].path || path)
                  .then(function(complete) {
                    console.log("complete:", complete);
                    event.target.value = null;
                  });
              } else {
                if (dir[0] instanceof File && dir[0].size > 0) {
                  return Promise.resolve(dir)
                    .then(function(complete) {
                      console.log("complete:", complete);
                    })
                } else {
                  if (dir[0].size == 0) {
                    throw new Error("could not process '" + dir[0].name + "' directory" + " at drop event at firefox, upload folders at 'Choose folder...' input");
                  }
                }
              }
            }).catch(function(err) {
              console.log(err)
            })
        }

        var reader = new FileReader();
        reader.onload = function(e) {
          text = reader.result;
          console.log("FileReader.result", text);
          button.removeAttribute("disabled");
        }

        reader.onerror = function(err) {
          console.log(err, err.loaded, err.loaded === 0, file);
          button.removeAttribute("disabled");
        }

        reader.onprogress = function(e) {
          console.log(e, e.lengthComputable, e.loaded, e.total);
        }

        reader.readAsArrayBuffer(file);

      }

      function handleText() {

        // do stuff with `text`: `reader.result` from `addDoc`
        display.textContent = text;
        button.setAttribute("disabled", "disabled");
        // set `text` to `null` if not needed or referenced again
        text = null;
      }
    }
  </script>
</head>

<body>
  <input type="file" id="myfile" webkitdirectory directory allowdirs>
  <button type="button" disabled>Add Document</button>
  <br>
  <br>
  <textarea id="DisplayText"></textarea>
</body>

</html>
```

plnkr http://plnkr.co/edit/8Ovw3IlYKI8BYsLhzV88?p=preview

---

You can use `change` event attached to `#myfile` element to handle file selection action by user.

Substitute `<textarea>` element for `<p>` element to display result of `load` event from `.readAsText()` call.

To display `.result` of `FileReader` at `click` at `button` element, set variable `text` to `reader.result` within `load` event of `FileReader` at `click` event at `button` set `.textContent` of `#DisplayText` element to variable referencing previously set `reader.result`.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <style>
    body {
      height: 400px;
    }
    textarea {
      width:95%;
      height: inherit;
    }
  </style>
<head>
  <script>
    window.onload = function() {
        var button = document.querySelector("#myfile + button");
        var input = document.getElementById("myfile");
        var display = document.getElementById("DisplayText");
        var text = null;
        input.addEventListener("change", addDoc);
        button.addEventListener("click", handleText)

        function addDoc(event) {
          var file = this.files[0]
          var reader = new FileReader();      
          reader.onload = function(e) {
            text = reader.result;
            button.removeAttribute("disabled");
          }

          reader.onerror = function(err) {
            console.log(err, err.loaded
                        , err.loaded === 0
                        , file);
            button.removeAttribute("disabled");
          }

          reader.readAsText(event.target.files[0]);
        }

        function handleText() {
          
          // do stuff with `text`: `reader.result` from `addDoc`
          display.textContent = text;
          button.setAttribute("disabled", "disabled");
          // set `text` to `null` if not needed or referenced again
          text = null; 
        }
    }
  </script>
</head>

<body>
  <input type="file" id="myfile" accept="text/*">
  <button type="button" disabled>Add Document</button><br><br>
  <textarea id="DisplayText"></textarea>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: @sushmithaP See [2.9.8 Monkey patch for Blob and FileList objects](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/#monkey-patch-for-blob-and-filelist-objects) , [File API](https://w3c.github.io/FileAPI/)

Comment: ,Thank you for the response.But in addition to that ,how deleting file at local filesystem after browsing and before adddoc() is not effecting reader.result.Is it creating any cache?

Comment: @sushmithaP At `html` `<input type="file">` element `id` is `"myfile"`, at `javascript` you reference `#myFile`, which does not appear at `html` at Question. Also, use `change` event attached to `<input type="file">` element to handle file being selected from local filesystem.

Comment: @sushmithaP Found a bug at firefox where files dropped at `<textarea>` element sets `.value` of `<textarea>` to fulll path to file at local filesystem.

Answer (score 1):

The FileReader object lets web applications asynchronously read the contents of files (or raw data buffers) stored on the user's computer, using File or Blob objects to specify the file or data to read.

File objects may be obtained from a FileList object returned as a result of a user selecting files using the  element, from a drag and drop operation's DataTransfer object, or from the mozGetAsFile() API on an HTMLCanvasElement.

The **readAsText** method is used to read the contents of the specified Blob or File. When the read operation is complete, the readyState is changed to DONE, the loadend is triggered, and the result attribute contains the contents of the file as a text string.

**Syntax**

```
instanceOfFileReader.readAsText(blob[, encoding]);
```

**Parameters**

**Blob**

The Blob or File from which to read.

**encoding** Optional

A string specifying the encoding to use for the returned data. By default, UTF-8 is assumed if this parameter is not specified.

For the metadata about a file we can check the File object `F` such that:
F has a readability state of OPENED.
F refers to the bytes byte sequence.
`F.size` is set to the number of total bytes in bytes.
`F.name` is set to n.
`F.type` is set to t.

> Note: The type t of a File is considered a parsable MIME type if the ASCII-encoded string representing the File object's type, when
>   converted to a byte sequence, does not return undefined for the parse
>   MIME type algorithm [MIMESNIFF].

`F.lastModified` is set to d.

See more about browser compatibility and detailed document for [FileReader](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/FileReader), [File](https://www.w3.org/TR/file-upload/#dfn-file) and [readAsText](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader/readAsText) at MDN, also this [W3C draft for FileApi](https://w3c.github.io/FileAPI/)

Comment: How does you Answer address questions presented at OP _"Is it that the FileReader gets binded as soon as the file is browsed?

Also can we check whether the system Readonly Attribute with FileReader similar to Java File.canread()?"_?

Comment: added all available file attributes as mentioned in w3c, but still readonly is not there

Comment: Have you tried reading a file or folder having read-only permission set at filesystem? _"added all available file attributes as mentioned in w3c, but still readonly is not there"_ That is part of Question. Your Answer does not address that portion of Question, or these Questions _"After browsing a file from local system I tried to delete the "browsed" document form the folder before clicking on addDoc(). After clicking the button I could still see Filereader.result is not null and could display all the content."_.

Comment: @guest271314 I tried files with read only permission, check a woking demo at https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/dndfiles/.
This demo shows all available options and attributes from file.

I was able to not only read, but also split the "Read only" files.

The files are actually replicated in the browser temp directory before upload as multi-part  form data and  you are allowed to read the "Read only" files, we cannot just overwrite or modify them

Comment: _"I tried files with read only permission, check a woking demo at html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/dndfiles. This demo shows all available options and attributes from file. I was able to not only read, but also split the "Read only" files. The files are actually replicated in the browser temp directory before upload as multi-part form data and you are allowed to read the "Read only" files, we cannot just overwrite or modify them"_ Interesting. Consider sharing what you found with description of how to reproduce at https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1311823

Comment: Can you create a plnkr to demonstrate?

Answer (score 1):

Use this instead:-

```js
function loadFileAsText()
{
    var fileToLoad = document.getElementById("fileToLoad").files[0];
 
    var fileReader = new FileReader();
    fileReader.onload = function(fileLoadedEvent) 
    {
        var textFromFileLoaded = fileLoadedEvent.target.result;
        document.getElementById("inputTextToSave").innerText = textFromFileLoaded;
    };
    fileReader.readAsText(fileToLoad, "UTF-8");
}
```

```html
        <p>Select a File to Load:</p>
        <input type="file" id="fileToLoad"><button onclick="loadFileAsText()">Load Selected File</button>
            <br>
            <br>
            <br>
            <p>Text file loaded:</p>
         <p id="inputTextToSave"></p>
```