# How to show the preview of the input photo in page?

Tags: javascript, html, angular, input

I have an img tag and an input type file,

**Functionality**

The functionality is i will input one jpg file using input type file, i need to show this image in the image tag.

**How is it possible in angular 2 ?**

**My tries**
I tried to get the file path on change event of input button and assign it to the src of image file.

Tried to solve it using an external js file.

but both these tries are failure, whats the solution for this.

**Code**

HTML

```
   <img [src]="imagePath" width="100px">
   <input type="file" multiple (change)="onUpload(input)" #input >
```

Component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit, NgModule } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-form',
  templateUrl: './form.component.html',
})
export class FormComponent implements OnInit {
//DECLARATION
  imagePath:string;

  constructor() { 
    this.onInitial();
    }

  ngOnInit() {}

  onInitial(){
    this.imagePath="../../assets/images/1.jpg"
  }
  onUpload(event){
    console.log(event);
  }

}
```

What the code i need to write inside the **onUpload()** to assign the path of the input image to the variable imagePath.

Please help me.

Answer (score 2):

Have not tried Angular2. Though you should be able to set `img` `src` to `Blob URL` of first `File` object of `input.files` `FileList`.

At chromium, chrome you can get `webkitRelativePath` from `File` object, though the property is "non-standard" and possibly could be set to an empty string; that is, should not be relied on for the relative path to the selected file at user filesystem.

[`File.webkitRelativePath`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/File/webkitRelativePath)

> This feature is non-standard and is not on a standards track. Do not
>   use it on production sites facing the Web: it will not work for every
>   user. There may also be large incompatibilities between
>   implementations and the behavior may change in the future.

[`File`](https://wicg.github.io/entries-api/#dom-file-webkitrelativepath)

> The `webkitRelativePath` attribute of the `File` interface must return
>   the relative path of the file, or the empty string if not specified.

[4.10.5.1.18. File Upload state (type=file)](https://w3c.github.io/html/sec-forms.html#file-upload-state-typefile)

> [EXAMPLE 16](https://w3c.github.io/html/sec-forms.html#example-8eea6b94) For historical reasons, the [`value`](https://w3c.github.io/html/sec-forms.html#dom-htmlinputelement-value) IDL attribute
>   prefixes the file name with the string `"C:\fakepath\"`. Some legacy
>   user agents actually included the full path (which was a security
>   vulnerability). As a result of this, obtaining the file name from the
>   `value` IDL attribute in a backwards-compatible way is non-trivial.

See also [How FileReader.readAsText in HTML5 File API works?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40146768/how-filereader-readastext-in-html5-file-api-works/40146883#40146883)

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
</head>

<body>
  <img src="" width="100px" alt="preview">
  <input type="file" multiple onchange="onUpload(this)" id="input" accepts="image/*" />
  <br><label for="input"></label>
  <script>
    let url;
    function onUpload(element) {
      console.log(element)
      let file = element.files[0];
      if (url) {
        URL.revokeObjectURL(url);
      }
      url = URL.createObjectURL(file);
      if ("webkitRelativePath" in file 
          && file.webkitRelativePath !== "") {
        element.labels[0].innerHTML = file.webkitRelativePath;
      } else {
        element.labels[0].innerHTML = element.value;
      }
      element.previousElementSibling.src = url;
      element.value = null;     
    }
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: i had tried this But the element object doesn't have file array.
Getting this error .
https://gyazo.com/fe9d29efa7bea44db8445c6003a1f4a0

Comment: Nothing appears at link. `FileList` does not return an array.

Comment: Is `input` defined at `(change)="onUpload(input)"`?

Comment: i changed to (change)="onUpload(input)"
Now 
    if ("webkitRelativePath" in file) {
      console.log(file.webkitRelativePath);
    }
this condition is true but while loging the file.webkitRelativePath it will show blank

Comment: There is no guarantee that `.webkitRelativePath` with be other than an empty string `""`. `element.value` should return `C:\fakepath\relativePathHere.ext` to resource, not full path to resource at user filesystem. See [4.10.5.1.18. File Upload state (type=file)](https://w3c.github.io/html/sec-forms.html#file-upload-state-typefile) , [How FileReader.readAsText in HTML5 File API works?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40146768/how-filereader-readastext-in-html5-file-api-works/40146883#40146883)

Comment: I had consoled File 

then i get the result as 
https://i.gyazo.com/f6d77108348319abd4d433dc17791fdc.png

Only get the file name no file path is there

Comment: @AswinKV Yes. Full path to file at user filesystem should not be included. The there is no guarantee that `.webkitRelativePath` will be other than an empty string `""`. Have you read the links at previous comment? Use `element.value` to get the `fakepath`

Answer (score 0):

At last i got the answer my self,

**https://github.com/ribizli/ng2-imageupload**

this will work for you. It may help you for this issue.