# How to get the path of selected folder in javascript or node js

Tags: javascript, node.js

I want to get the path of selected folder. Here is my code:

```
<input style="display:none;" id="fileDialog" type="file" webkitdirectory />

var chooser = document.querySelector('#fileDialog');
    chooser.addEventListener("change", function(evt) {
      console.log(this.value);
    }, false);
    chooser.click();
```

Using this code i'm getting a fakepath.

Is there anyway in node.js,so i can get the path of my selected folder.
I'm using express framework in node.js.

Comment: You're talking about the path of the file on the client machine, right?

Comment: path of a folder that i selected from window dialog

Answer (score 1):

There's no way for you to get the path of the file selected in an `input type="file"` at all, full stop. Not on the browser, and not transmitted to the server for you to use in Node/Express. That information is simply not available to you. Browsers let you know the name of the file, but that's it.

Comment: Is there any API to do it?

Comment: @SumitSarkar: No, the path of the file that was selected is not made available by the browser *at all*.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Note, there is a bug at Firefox 47 where the full path is provided at `drop` event when `drop` occurs at `<textarea>` element, see [How FileReader.readAsText in HTML5 File API works?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40146768/how-filereader-readastext-in-html5-file-api-works)

Comment: @T.J. Crowder thanks for your response, but there is some API called electron, which let you know the path of selected folder.

Comment: @SumitSarkar: [Electron](https://electron.atom.io/) isn't an API, it's a framework for building **desktop** applications with web technologies. I said the **browser** doesn't make this information available; and it doesn't. Electron apps use web technologies, but they are not browsers.

Comment: Thanks @T.J. Crowder