# Can JavaScript read files on the hard drive?

Tags: javascript, readfile

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13405129/javascript-create-and-save-file) I have learned that it is possible with JavaScript in HTML to create files offline and save them on the hard disk.

But what about reading files? Can JavaScript access, say one of my .txt files on my self phone and display the read data (or at least place it in the local storage)?

I know that it is possible with PHP, but there is no PHP on my cellphone, while HTML is always there.

Comment: how would the javascript access a txt file on your cellphone? How would it know where to look? There aren't really file directories, nonetheless standardized file storage.

Comment: @Wold: do you mean "let alone"?

Comment: The short answer is no, because of the secure sandboxing the browser does around the HTML + JavaScript. Even the successful (non-deprecated) filesystem-ish APIs like LocalStorage don't give you unfettered access to the filesystem. JavaScript under Node.js could do this with no problem, however.

Comment: At least, the manifest, a cookie, else no.

Comment: @Wold - Can you, please, elaborate on standardized file storage? What is it?

Comment: @hacksalot - Is Node.js one of the commands in JavaScript? (Sorry if my question is too stupid - mt knowledge of JavaScript is very primitive)

Comment: @pirs - Do you mean that HTML can still leave some info on my cellphone as a cookie? What is manifest?

Comment: @brilliant https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/Add-ons/WebExtensions/manifest.json

Comment: @pirs - Thanks for that link!

Comment: You can use `<input type="file">` and `FileReader` to read files stored at local filesystem, see [File API](https://w3c.github.io/FileAPI/)

Comment: @Ryan yah that's embarrassing. I'm not too familiar with storage on android, but there are third party applications on ios that allow file storage, where you can interact with them from the web. But there isn't really any plain file storage that I'm aware of.

Comment: @guest271314 - Is that some kind of application that I need to install on my cellphone first?

Comment: @brilliant No, though you would need to compose the HTML and JavaScript. If trying at Chromium or Chrome to read `file:` protocol launch the browser with `--allow-file-access-from-files` flag, without other Chrome instances running, or use a different `--user-data-dir`, see [Read local XML with JS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41279589/read-local-xml-with-js/)

Comment: @guest271314 - I see. Thanks a lot. It looks quite promising!

Comment: @guest271314 - Thanks again. Actually, your comment is a valid answer and a solution to my problem. Why don't you re-write your comment as an answer and I will give the right credit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `<input type="file">` and `FileReader` to read files stored at local filesystem, see [File API](https://w3c.github.io/FileAPI/); also [How FileReader.readAsText in HTML5 File API works?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40146768/how-filereader-readastext-in-html5-file-api-works/).

If trying at Chromium or Chrome to read `file:` protocol launch the browser with `--allow-file-access-from-files` flag, without other Chrome instances running, or use a different `--user-data-dir`, see [Read local XML with JS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41279589/read-local-xml-with-js/).