# FileReader Error from "How FIleReader.readAsText in HTML5 File API works"

Tags: javascript, html, file, filereader

After adapting the [How FileReader.readAsText in HTML5 File API works?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40146768/how-filereader-readastext-in-html5-file-api-works) code to my purposes. It gives me an error.

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of null

#### My Adapted Javascript Code

```
var button = document.querySelector('#fileInput + button');
var input = document.getElementById('#fileInput');
var text = null;
input.addEventListener("change", addDoc);
button.addEventListener("click", handleText);

function addDoc(event) {
    var file = this.files[0];
    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = function(e) {
        text = reader.result;
        button.removeAttribute("disabled");
    };

    reader.onerror = function(err) {
        console.log(err, err.loaded, err.loaded === 0, file);
        button.removeAttribute("diabled");
    };

    reader.readAsText(event.target.files[0]);
    console.log(reader.readAsText(event.target.files[0]));
}

function handleText() {
    addtoPreviousOutput();
    changeOutputParagraph(text);
    button.setAttribute("disabled", "disabled");
}

function changeOutputParagraph(newText) {
    var element = document.getElementById("output");
    element.innerHTML = newText;
}

function addtoPreviousOutput() {
    var previousOutput = document.getElementById("output").innerHTML;
    var previousOutput_sOutput = document.getElementById("previousOutput").innerHTML + "<br />";
    console.log(previousOutput);
    console.log(previousOutput_sOutput);
    document.getElementById("previousOutput").innerHTML = previousOutput_sOutput + previousOutput;
}
```

#### My Adapted HTML5 Code

```
<input type="file" id="fileInput" accept="text/*"/>
<button type="button">Add Document</button>
<p id="output"></p>
```

What is my error caused by and how can I fix it?
Thanks, DS_Secret.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When the code

```
var input = document.getElementById('#fileInput');
input.addEventListener("change", addDoc);
```

fails with the message `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of null`, it follows that `document.getElementById('#fileInput')` returns null.

This, in turn, means that there was no element with the ID `'#fileInput'` at the time the code ran. This is true, you only have a similarly id-ed element with `id="fileInput"`, without a leading `#` character. So set input like

```
var input = document.getElementById('fileInput');
```

or

```
var input = document.querySelector('#fileInput');
```

In addition, make sure that the JavaScript code does not run too early. Normally, everything that depends on the DOM should only be called once the [`DOMContentLoaded` event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/DOMContentLoaded) has fired, especially if your script tags located are in the document head. Otherwise, when the JavaScript runs, the DOM may not include the desired elements yet.

Answer (score 1):

I thing you are using the method document.getElementById wrong.

Try using

```
var input = document.getElementById('fileInput');
```

Instead of

```
var input = document.getElementById('#fileInput');
```