# Using FileReader to read a JSON file?

Tags: javascript, typescript, filereader

I'm trying to read a JSON file I have, uploaded by the user, and try to copy it to an array. However, with a .readAsText(), the return I get has the formatting of a string (obviously), such as including \" and \n and other string-like properties.

Is there a way I can use FileReader (or any other form of reading files, that don't involve a server) to read the JSON file and have it return just the plain JSON?

For example, having it return

```
[
  {"hello": "world"}
]
```

or

```
[{"hello": "world"}]
```

and not

```
"[\n{\"hello\": \"world\"}\n]"
```

?

Edit: I am now aware of the JSON.parse(text) method, but I'm getting an error when parsing the FileReader object

```
 let fileUploaded = new FileReader();
 fileUploaded.readAsText(MY_JSON_FILE);
 console.log(JSON.parse(fileUploaded));
```

it returns the error `error TS2345: Argument of type 'FileReader' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string'`

Can I get what i read with FileReader to another var that is a string, and then parse that new var?

Comment: Do you mean to get the JSON string decoded automatically into JavaScript object?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Safely turning a JSON string into an object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45015/safely-turning-a-json-string-into-an-object)

Comment: As per the link in my comment above, you want `JSON.parse(text);` to turn that into an object.

Comment: @Archer I was not aware of JSON.parse, and it does seem to be near the solution, but I'm getting the error that I can't parse a FileReader obj... anyway I can pass the information to another obj to hold the string, and then parse that obj?

Comment: `JSON` is a string format. What do you mean by _"parse a FileReader obj"_? Can you include the HTML and JavaScript code that uses `FileReader` at the question? See https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: @guest271314 I've updated the question. Hopefully it will better explain my problem.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The code at the question uses [`FileReader`](https://www.w3.org/TR/FileAPI/#dfn-filereader) incorrectly.

`FileReader` `.readAs<Type>` operation is asynchronous. `FileReader` has `load` and `loadend` events where the `result` property of `event.target` and `FileReader` instance is the resulting asynchronously processed data.

Do not parse the `FileReader` object itself.

`.readAs<Type>` expects a [`Blob`](https://www.w3.org/TR/FileAPI/#dfn-Blob) to be passed as parameter, not a JavaScript plain object.

```js
const MY_JSON_FILE = [{
  "hello": "world"
}];

let json = JSON.stringify(MY_JSON_FILE);

const blob = new Blob([json], {type:"application/json"});

const fr = new FileReader();

fr.addEventListener("load", e => {
  console.log(e.target.result, JSON.parse(fr.result))
});

fr.readAsText(blob);
```

Comment: This makes a lot of sense, and seems to be the correct answer, but I'm getting an error saying "Property 'result' does not exist on type 'EventTarget'", on the console.log and the .result s that are used... Any idea why?

Comment: I dont seem to be able to... The error might be on my side, I'll take a better look at it.I'm a bit new to all this, so sorry for not being as clear as I should!

Comment: @JoséM. See also [How FileReader.readAsText in HTML5 File API works?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40146768/how-filereader-readastext-in-html5-file-api-works/)

Comment: just popping in for a quick note that the good old IT fix of "turn it off an on again" seamed to "fix" whatever bug was happening. It's working now! Thank you once again!